# How to give a padding in between x-axis labels in React-Native-Chart-Kit?

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

Is there a way to give a custom space/padding in between x-axis Labels in React-Native-Chart-Kit? Example if we have labels from Jan-Dec, x-axis labels in the chart gets very compact. And even if we give a custom space between x-axis Labels then how do we give a Horizontal scroll feature for the full chart since it overflows onto the right side. Tried with following. Didn't work. Please help. Thanks.

```
propsForLabels: {
            fontSize: "14",
            fill: "rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)",
            fontWeight: 500,
            padding: 5
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `horizontalOffset` or check this issue looks like you can use patch or fork from this issue https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/issues/538 to resolve your problem.

Comment: Noted Thanks alot. I tried with another way which I have replaced the "View" tag with the "<ScrollView horizontal={true}>. And increased the width attribute of the Chart as {Dimensions.get("window").width * 2}.